# What ports does HP-SIM use to query servers?

Tags: hp

What ports do I need to open in my firewalls to allow my server running HP-SIM (HP Systems Insight Manager) to discover other servers (manually and automatic) and query their status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "By default, Systems Insight Manager
> uses sport [sic] 5989 to communicate
> with the WBEM server of the systems it
> monitors." [1](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02786632/c02786632.pdf)

From the Windows install guide ([page 28 here](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02786423/c02786423.pdf)), it also lists these ports and protocols, but I'm not sure how many are always needed.

> TCP 2301, 2381, 5988, 5989, 22 (SSH), 80
>
> UDP 161 (SNMP)
>
> ICMP

Answer (score 2):

**SO** many it's not funny, it really is a long list and depends on what you're looking at managing. Basically just download the full big PDF installation manual, it's all in there but you should read it properly if you can.